# JAX-RS Jersey JSON preserve null using annotations

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

How do I have JAXB preserve nulls when receiving a JSON sting that contains a null or "" value.

String:`{"id":null,"fname":"John","region":""}`

returns Object:

```
 Person {
    Integer id = 0
    String fname = "John"
    Region regions = 0 }
```

I would like it to return null instead of 0

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class<?>[] types = {Person.class};

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(), types);
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        for (Class<?> c : types) {
            if (c.equals(objectType)) {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Person.class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement` I've tried looking into Jackson annotations but have had no success.

Comment: Same problem here. Someone got a solution for this problems. The ObjectMapper seems to be ignored by Jersey

Comment: Same problem as well. I also tried using ObjectMapper and Jersey failed to pick it up as well. I'm not sure that using ObjectMapper is the simplest solution anyway...

Comment: My similar issue has been resolved. You can see if it helps you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420641/including-null-elements-in-json-output-of-jersey-restful-api-with-jaxb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below is an example of how this can be done with MOXy.

**Person**

MOXy will unmarshal the `Person` object as you want without specifying any metadata.  To have the output JSON contain null values, you can use the `@XmlElement(nillable=true)` annotation (see [Binding to JSON & XML - Handling Null](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html)).

```
package forum8748537;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    Integer id;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    String fname;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    Region regions;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain classes with the following entry (see [Specifying EclipseLink MOXy as Your JAXB Provider](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum8748537;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        properties.put("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Person.class}, properties);

        StringReader json = new StringReader("{\"id\":null,\"fname\":\"John\",\"region\":\"\"}");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Person person = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(json), Person.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
{
   "id" : null,
   "fname" : "John",
   "regions" : null
}
```

**Using MOXy in a JAX-RS Application**

For an example of using MOXy in a JAX-RS application see:

- [MOXy as Your JAX-RS JSON Provider - Server Side](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html)
- [MOXy as Your JAX-RS JSON Provider - Client Side](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider_15.html)

Answer (score 1):

As of JSON-B JSR-367 (JAX-RS 2.1 JSR-370), the following annotation works instead of @XmlElement.

```
@JsonbProperty(nillable = true)
```