# Including null elements in JSON output of Jersey RESTful API with JAXB

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have a class that I would like to expose through a Jersey RESTful API. It looks similar to this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Data {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

My problem is that these fields may be null, in which case the field is omitted from the JSON output. I would like all fields to be present regardless of their value. For example, if lastName is null, the JSON output will be:

```
{
   "firstName" : "Oleksi"
}
```

instead of what I want:

```
{
   "firstName" : "Oleksi",
   "lastName" : null
}
```

I have a JAXBContextResolver (an implementation of ContextResolver) that looks like this:

```
@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

     // internal state
    private final JAXBContext context;    
    private final Set<Class> types; 
    private final Class[] cTypes = { Data.class };


    public JAXBContextResolver() 
    throws Exception {

        types = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(cTypes));
        context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().humanReadableFormatting(true).build(), cTypes);
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {

        return (types.contains(objectType)) ? context : null;
    }
}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to get that desired output for a while, but I've had no luck. I'm open to trying other ContextResolvers/Serializers, but I haven't been able to find one that works, so code examples would be nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s JSON binding, the correct mapping would be the following.  You could try it with your provider to see if it would work also:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Data {
    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    public String firstName;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    public String lastName;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

---

**UPDATE 2**

EclipseLink 2.4 includes `MOXyJsonProvider` which is an implementation of `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` that you can use directly to leverage MOXy's JSON binding

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

**UPDATE 1**

The following `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` may work better for you:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MOXyJSONProvider implements
    MessageBodyReader<Object>, MessageBodyWriter<Object>{

    @Context
    protected Providers providers;

    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            try {
                Class<?> domainClass = getDomainClass(genericType);
                Unmarshaller u = getJAXBContext(domainClass, mediaType).createUnmarshaller();
                u.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", mediaType.toString());
                u.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
                return u.unmarshal(new StreamSource(entityStream), domainClass).getValue();
            } catch(JAXBException jaxbException) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(jaxbException);
            }
    }

    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
        WebApplicationException {
        try {
            Class<?> domainClass = getDomainClass(genericType);
            Marshaller m = getJAXBContext(domainClass, mediaType).createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", mediaType.toString());
            m.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
            m.marshal(object, entityStream);
        } catch(JAXBException jaxbException) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(jaxbException);
        }
    }

    public long getSize(Object t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    private JAXBContext getJAXBContext(Class<?> type, MediaType mediaType)
        throws JAXBException {
        ContextResolver<JAXBContext> resolver
            = providers.getContextResolver(JAXBContext.class, mediaType);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        if(null == resolver || null == (jaxbContext = resolver.getContext(type))) {
            return JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {type}, null); 
        } else {
            return jaxbContext;
        }
    }

    private Class<?> getDomainClass(Type genericType) {
        if(genericType instanceof Class) {
            return (Class<?>) genericType;
        } else if(genericType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            return (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) genericType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I can't quite get it to work. Can you please provide more details on any additional code changes that would be required (other than what's listed above). For instance, do I have to change my JAXBContextResolver class?

Comment: I've also had difficulties downloading the required dependancies for this project. I tried looking at this document to no avail. http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven

Comment: Here is an example pom.xml:  https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110819/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: I downloaded and tried it with the JAXBProvider and it didn't work. An empty lastName is output lastName :  { "nil" : "true" }. I switched to  MOXyJSONProvider given in your example and then I get an exception: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.media-type value: application/json
 at MOXyJSONProvider.writeTo(MOXyJSONProvider.java:58)

Comment: Does it have to be version 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT? I'd prefer to use the most up-to-date stable release (2.3.2)

Comment: @Oleksi - The JSON binding is being added to 2.4.0, instead of a snap shot you can use a milestone 2.4.0-M18 http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/milestones.php.  We will be releasing as part of the Eclipse Juno release this summer and should be entering the release candidate stage very soon.

Comment: I downloaded and tried it with 2.4.0-M18, but I'm still getting the same exception. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like getJAXBContext() in MOXyJSONProvider might not be picking up a context correctly (and thus creating a JAXB context that doesn't know what "eclipselink.media-type" is). Do we also need to provide a JAXBContext? If so, how do we tell MOXy about it?

Comment: @Oleksi - I've updated my answer with a version that may work better for you.

Comment: Tried the new version, but it still doesn't work (same exception). I think there's some type confusion in getJAXBContext(). Should it be working with avax.xml.bind.JAXBContext or org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext? Or both? Also, do I need the jaxb.properties file, and if so, then where should it be?

Comment: Fixed! The problem was the we left the old JAXB provider hanging around with it's @Provider annotation. It seems to work now. Thanks a a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score -2):

Java null is JavaScript's undefined.  If you want to convert a Java null to a JavaScript null, you'll need to consult your conversion library.