# Avoid responding JSON field with particular value

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I'm using Jersey and Jackson to build a web application. Responses will be returned by using logic similar to the code snippets below. (unrelated parts are deleted)

```
public Response toResponse() {
    String name = // some methods to get name
    Integer score = // some methods to get score
    final MyDTO dto = new MyDTO(name, score);
    return Response
        .ok()
        .encoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .entity(dto)
        .build();
}
```

And the `MyDTO` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public final class MyDTO {
    @NotNull final private String name;
    @NotNull final private Integer score;
    // constructor, getters, setters...
}
```

And I'm allowed to have only non-null values in MyDTO. 
What I want to achieve is to hide `score` field in the JSON response when the `score` exactly equals to 0.
I looked into questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420641/including-null-elements-in-json-output-of-jersey-restful-api-with-jaxb) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708386/want-to-hide-some-fields-of-an-object-that-are-being-mapped-to-json-by-jackson), but cannot manage to find a usable answer.

Example:
when John's score was 1: `{"name": "John", "score": 1}`
when John's score was 0: `{"name": "John"}`

Comment: what do you mean by hide? do you want to complete remove it or just set it as private?

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal complete remove the field from the JSON response

Comment: i can't think of any clever way, but you could create another class that doesn't have the `score` field and use that one when necessary.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal Thanks for you comment and yes, using another class can achieve this. But actually I have 3 fields need to meet this requirement, so I'm wondering if there's any better solutions rather than generating 4 different classes.

Comment: I propose you to have all non-primitive types like Integer instead of int and use the @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) annotation

Comment: @BalakrishnaAvulapati Yeah, I think `@JsonInclude` will be a perfect option if it supports regular expression.

Comment: @choasia : The NON_NULL "indicates that only properties with non-null values are to be included.", Seems like a sound proposal! https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_NULL

Comment: @BalakrishnaAvulapati: You should type that up as an answer.

Comment: You can do with jackson filter

Comment: @Henrik appreciate your comment

Comment: @Jerry06 Would you please give more information?

Comment: @choasia: Perhaps this http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Comment: @Henrik this link is definitely useful. Although it is much more verbose, it is more flexible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the answer by @Henrik changing the annotation to [JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT). Hope this is what you are expecting

Comment: Although I cannot define the default value by myself, it did work for current requirement! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to try out @BalakrishnaAvulapati's proposal, and it definitely seems like the correct approach.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public static class Player {
    private String nick;
    private Integer score;

    // Omitting getter/setter for nick field

    public Integer getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score == 0 ? null : Integer.valueOf(score);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it is a great approach but it will cause some side effect since `MyDTO` is not supposed to have any field with null value. It's a simplified code snippet, I'm sorry that I didn't mention it in the question. I'd appreciate you if you could give an answer without setting it to null.

Comment: @choasia : Well, if I had another approach, I wouldn't have "stolen" this rather elegant one. :)

Comment: @choasia : But you might want to start researching creating your own, specialized serializer.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into it.