# How to configure container to include POJO's null properties to final JSON using only JAX-RS standard?

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

In Java EE, how to configure container to render null properties using only JAX-RS standard, without annotating or otherwise configuring an actual JAR-RS implementation? And is it possible at all? As an example, lets say I have an end-point and a pojo, and I am returning POJO with some properties set to null. As a result I'd like to see such null properties to be included in JSON too.

POJO:

```
class Pojo{  
    String name;
    String value;
}
```

End-point (configured to produce JSON):

```
Response getPojo(){
    Pojo p = new Pojo();
    p.setName("somename");
    return Response.ok(p).build();
    }
```

Will produce:

```
{"name":"somename"} // no value at all
```

While I'd like to have it like:

```
{"name":"somename", "value":null} // value is null
```

---

Are there any Java EE standard ways to configure such behaviour without messing up with underlying JAX-RS implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAX-RS Jersey JSON preserve null using annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748537/jax-rs-jersey-json-preserve-null-using-annotations)

Answer (score 1):

Annotating POJO property with

`javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(nillable=true)`

solves the problem. In the example above POJO could have a getter for ID like:

```
    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: Which is exactly what is says in the duplicate